# Why in TCL switch, "$z" is not as same as ONE

Tags: tcl

```
set x "ONE"
set y 1
set z ONE
# This is probably the easiest and cleanest form of the command
# to remember:
switch $x {
    "$z" {
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
    }
    ONE {
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
    }
    TWO {
        set y1 [expr {$y+2}]
        puts "MATCH TWO. $y + two is $y1"
    }
    THREE {
        set y1 [expr {$y+3}]
        puts "MATCH THREE. $y + three is $y1"
    }
    default {
        puts "$x is NOT A MATCH"
    }
}

switch $x "$z" {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
} ONE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
} TWO {
    set y1 [expr {$y+2}]
    puts "MATCH TWO. $y + two is $y1"
} THREE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+3}]
    puts "MATCH THREE. $y + three is $y1"
} default {
    puts "$x does not match any of these choices"
}
```

In the first which print `MATCH ONE. 1 + one is 2`. In the second which print `MATCH $z. 1 + ONE is 2`. I don't understand why.

First I think in the first which `"$z"` is in `{}` so it is explained as `"$z"` and in the second which `"$z"` is not in `{}` so it is explained as `"ONE"`.

But I tried to print `"$z"` in the first switch in ONE, just like this

```
switch $x {
    "$z" {
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
    }
    ONE {
        puts "$z"
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
    }
    TWO {
        set y1 [expr {$y+2}]
        puts "MATCH TWO. $y + two is $y1"
    }
    THREE {
        set y1 [expr {$y+3}]
        puts "MATCH THREE. $y + three is $y1"
    }
    default {
        puts "$x is NOT A MATCH"
    }
}
```

I find `"$z"` is print as `ONE`

So the result of `"$z"` `"ONE"` is not as same as `ONE` in the first which? Can anyone help me to answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy to see what is going on if you prepend the `list` command:

```
% list switch $x {
    "$z" {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
    }
    ONE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
switch ONE {
    "$z" {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
    }
    ONE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
    }
}
```

The second form:

```
% list switch $x "$z" {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
} ONE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
}
switch ONE ONE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
} ONE {
    set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
    puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
}
```

As you can see, it's the braces that prevent the `$z` from expanding into "ONE".

But, you say, when you put `$z` within the second clause:

```
switch $x {
    "$z" {
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
    }
    ONE {
        puts "$z"
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
    }
}
```

It gets printed as "ONE". Well, this is because when the second clause has been selected, its code part (only, and only after it has already been selected) is evaluated in the enclosing context, i.e. on the same level as the `switch` was evaluated.

If we simplify this further:

```
switch $x {$z {puts a$z} ONE {puts b$z}}
```

Here, `switch` gets two text arguments, `ONE` and `$z {puts a$z} ONE {puts b$z}` (for the latter, this is literally "dollar-sign, z, blank, open brace"... It's just text with no special meaning).

Within `switch`, the second argument takes on some meaning: it is now a list of labels and scripts (but the scripts are still just strings). The logic for evaluating it all is something like "if ONE is equal to 'dollar-sign+z', then evaluate the script {puts a$z} in the upper level; else if ONE is equal to ONE, evaluate the script {puts b$z} in the upper level".

Evaluating `puts b$z` in the upper level prints "bONE", because we are now back in a context where `$z` is understood as a variable substitution and not the string dollar-sign+z.

There are some ways to deal with variable substitution in `switch` labels, the simplest being to use the second form of the `switch` command without braces around the clause list. Another way is to use an `if` - `elseif` chain instead.

Comment: It's 4:40am here, and I'm not entirely awake. Hopefully, this still makes sense. Comment if it doesn't, and I'll have another look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `switch`, in the big braced form, is processing the contents of that big braced section *as a Tcl list* and not according to full Tcl script rules, and that disabled processing of `$` and `[…]` substitutions. (Some of those elements in the list are *then* interpreted as scripts, of course, but that's an inner layer of parsing.) In the second form, full Tcl substitutions are available, and so `"$z"` isn't expanded to just a dollar and a `z`, but rather a read of a variable.

Most of the time, the values being `switch`ed against are constants (as are the scripts) and the big braced form is ideal; it's (in my opinion) easier to write too. However, where complex substitutions are required, the other form is more suitable. That's exactly why it is there. Theoretically, you could instead build a list up with `list` and use that as in below, but I think that's pretty ugly code:

```
switch $x [list \
    "$z" {
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH \$z. $y + $z is $y1"
    } \
    ONE {
        set y1 [expr {$y+1}]
        puts "MATCH ONE. $y + one is $y1"
    } \
    TWO {
        set y1 [expr {$y+2}]
        puts "MATCH TWO. $y + two is $y1"
    } \
    THREE {
        set y1 [expr {$y+3}]
        puts "MATCH THREE. $y + three is $y1"
    } \
    default {
        puts "$x does not match any of these choices"
    }
]
```

There are some performance bonuses to using the forms with as many literals as possible. In particular, if all the “patterns” are things that can be determined at bytecode-compilation time to be literals (and all the bodies are literals, and exact matching — the default style — is used) then the `switch` is converted into a jump table, and those are pretty fast once you get a reasonable number of clauses. With non-constant patterns (or non-exact matching) each pattern has to be tested in sequence; there's no practical way to make that more efficient that I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no error about the lack of line continuation following the "default" block.

Comment: @glennjackman: the text within the brackets is processed as a script: there may be line breaks before or after, or between commands if there are more than one. Or the line breaks may be escaped, but they don't *have* to be.